# Random cell with index & match with extra criteria in another column

Tags: excel, google-sheets, random, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I got three columns: Level, Calculation and Answer.
To choose a random calculation, I use the formula: `=INDEX(B2:B16, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(B2:B16)))`

To get the related answer, I use the formula: `=INDEX($C$2:$C$16,MATCH(F2,$B$2:$B$16,0))`

Now I want to choose a random calculation based on the level in the first column. So instead of choosing a random calculation from the 15 calculations in column B, I want it to choose a random calculation from column B where column A for example is '2'.

Is this possible and if yes, how?

[Example of my spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqNCM.png)

Comment: Hi! Where is ```2``` going to be informed to be compared against in the ```match()``` function?...or does it have to be random as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY({FILTER(A2:C, A2:A<>""), RANDARRAY(COUNTA(A2:A))}, 
 "select Col2,Col3 where Col1 = 2 order by Col4 limit 1")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you put your chosen level in `G1`:

`=LET(ζ,FILTER(B2:B16,A2:A16=G1),INDEX(ζ,RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS(ζ))))`

Answer (score 0):

You could make a unique list of the levels and put that in a range to provide user entry for the level selector, then use the level to filter the table. It seems to work but you might want to test it.
[image of possible solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szlTU.png)